# get distinct count of substring of file name

Tags: c#, linq

I have a directory with a list of file names.

VAH007157100-pic1.jpg
VAH007157100-pic2.jpg
VAH007157100-pic3.jpg

WAZ009999200-pic1.jpg
WAZ009999200-pic2.jpg
WAZ009999200-pic3.jpg

I want to know the distinct count of substringing (0, 12).

This isn't working for some reason:

```
string[] originalFiles = Directory.GetFiles(SelectedDirectory);

private int GetDistinctPolicyCountInDirectory()
        {
            var prefixes = originalFiles
                .GroupBy(x => x.Substring(0, 12))
                .Select(y => new { Policy = y.Key, Count = y.Count() });

            return prefixes.Count();
        }
```

I keep getting 0. Am I missing anything here?

Please note that I do not want to do a split to get the numbers separated. I want to do it by substringing.

UPDATE -

```
private int GetDistinctPolicyCountInDirectory(string[] originalFiles)
        {
            var count = originalFiles.Distinct(x => Path.GetFileName(x).Substring(0, 12)).Count();

            return Convert.ToInt32(count);
        }
```

I'm running into an error here where it says: Error 1   Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer' because it is not a delegate type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd just consider using `.Distinct()`.

Also you need to strip it down to just the filename instead of the full file path.

```
originalFiles.Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x).Substring(0, 12))
             .Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: good point, however, as Julien mentioned below, I gotta do a path.getfilename as well. Thanks to both. trying this now.

Comment: @user1336632: no problems. That's what we're here for. I find `Distinct` is often overlooked.

Comment: I spoke too soon, my apologies. I'm getting an error: "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate type. Please see my edit above for the code I have now

Comment: @user1336632: Updated with fix.

Answer (score 2):

`GetFiles` returns an array of file names with full paths, including the directory. You want to compare only the file name, so you should consider using `Path.GetFileName`.

`GroupBy(x => Path.GetFileName(x).Substring(0, 12));`